# Haxe 3.4.0 installer used 'haxelib version' still reflects 3.3.0

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I wanted to use Visual Studio Code for HaxeFlixel development and the Haxe extension noted that I needed Haxe 3.4.0. I went ahead and downloaded the new installer from the website and installed it on my laptop running Windows 10. However after installing it turned out that calling 'haxelib version' in the command prompt it still returned 3.3.0.

I tried rebooting. Uninstalling then rebooting and installing again. I could find nothing in the system environmental variables that could cause it. Tried updating the Haxe on my Desktop, and had the same issue. Which is running windows 8.1 on it.

Does someone know what might be the cause? Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the Haxe version, use `haxe -version`. `haxelib` is a separate application and can have a version number that's different from the compiler's version.

Haxelib 3.3.0 appears to be the version shipped with Haxe 3.4.0-rc.1.